# Can the <html> tag have more than one xmlns attributes?

Tags: html

In IE9, I get the following error in console:

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error  subdomain.domain.com, line 2 character 1

The line that created this error is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
```

I don't get this error in Chrome.

I'm not able to precisely figure out what's gone wrong. I guess having more than one xmlns attributes in the html tag could be creating problem. I searched for this, but couldn't get the information. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure, the error occurs on that line? Try to give more than that line or a link to the site.

Comment: Hi Bastian,

Here's the link: http://living.tend.com/

IE 9 shows an error in its console.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: For sure it can have more than one namespace attribute if it defines different namespaces! Like you do with `xmlns:fb`.

Comment: @shareef - The point is that it does work, and that you have misinterpreted the error message. The error is occurring in a JavasScript file, and you need to post sufficient code and error information for us to determine what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

yes it can have more than one ...i have used it in fb:api

Comment: Ok ... so the xmlns attribute isn't causing the error. Then what could be wrong in the source code I shared in the question above?